# How to execute C++ program whenever a USB flash drive is inserted

Tags: usb, usb-drive, c++, udev

I have a C++ program that accesses USB pen drives/flash drives. It works for currently inserted flash drive. A normal C++ program doesn't execute until we run it. But I wanted the program to run automatically whenever a flash drive is inserted. How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For general use, If you would like to run your program for any USB storage. Use the driver for the rule match.

1. Add a `udev` rules file

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/90-detect-storage.rules
   ```
2. Add this rule

   ```
   ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="usb-storage", DRIVER=="sd", RUN+="/pathto/yourprogram"
   ```

   If you want your program to distinguish the disks, so it runs different operations, use (you can pass its serial number or any attribute you like):

   ```
   ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="usb-storage", DRIVER=="sd", RUN+="/pathto/yourprogram $env{ID_VENDOR_ID} $env{ID_MODEL_ID}"
   ```
3. Reload all rules

   ```
   sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
   ```
4. Unplug and replug the flash drive

**Notes:**

- I used this rule just to test which create a log when the rule is triggered:

  ```
  ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="usb-storage", DRIVER=="sd", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo $env{ID_VENDOR_ID} $env{ID_MODEL_ID} >> /home/username/Desktop/usb-storage.log'"
  ```
- You can comment the rules you don't want by adding `#` to the beginning of the line. Rules file can contain multiple rules.
- To check all the available `env` variables, use:

  ```
  ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="usb-storage", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo == >> /home/username/Desktop/usb-storage-env.log; env >> /home/username/Desktop/usb-storage-env.log'"
  ```
- To check for parameters to use for rule match, run:

  ```
  sudo udevadm info --name=/dev/sdb1 --attribute-walk
  ```

**References:**

- [Pass ATTR{idVendor} as argument in udev script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818987/pass-attridvendor-as-argument-in-udev-script)
- [Writing udev rules](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) by Daniel Drake

Comment: I like this approach, upvoting, congrats!

Comment: +150: Great answer: (AFAIK better than accepted) It makes a general rule for any USB device. In the acccepted answer the USB is restricted to a VID and a PID.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `udev` to run an albitrary command. To make it work, create a rule in `/etc/udev/rules.d/`:

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/my-usb-device.rules
```

And enter:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idProduct}=="XXXX", ATTRS{idVendor}=="YYYY", RUN+="/location/of/my/command"
```

**NOTE:** The `XXXX` and `YYYY` values will be taken from `lsusb` output.

Comment: I don't agree. The C++ program is a "command" after all. The user is asking for a solution to trigger that command. (He said: " But I wanted the program to run automatically whenever a flash drive is inserted. How could I do that?")

Comment: For this[ http://ideone.com/uOReNj ] output of lsusb, what will be the values of `XXXX` and `YYYY`?

Comment: If your pendrive is the Kingston than: XXXX= 0951, and YYYY =162f.

Comment: For letting my code trigger for every different pen drive, should I always update the "my-usb-device.rules" file?

Comment: YOu have to create rule for every device. Or better refactor your C++ code to run as daemon and observe the udev triggers.