# How to automatically run a program when certain device is pluged in?

Tags: usb, tty, automation

I have home made device that connects via USB port and I have made a c++ program for data acquisition from that device. I have modified the `/etc/udev/rules.d/50-ttyusb.rules` so that the device has read/write permissions when pluged. Now I would also like that when I plug-in the device my program (named `SQM_ver2`) would automatically run. How can I do this?

The socket assigned to device is `ttyACM0`. Using Ubuntu 14.04.

`lsusb` output for the device:

```
Bus 003 Device 005: ID ffff:0005
```

Edit:

I have modified my rules file as proposed by @steeldriver but it did not work. Note that my program uses Terminal window to output the data. I have always run it from Terminal but now it should open a Terminal by itself. Here I add also the relevant lines in `/var/log/syslog` file when the device is pluged-in:

```
Jun  1 22:21:04 user-Lenovo-G50-45 kernel: [267790.078011] usb 3-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
Jun  1 22:21:04 user-Lenovo-G50-45 kernel: [267790.187324] usb 3-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=ffff, idProduct=0005
Jun  1 22:21:04 user-Lenovo-G50-45 kernel: [267790.187339] usb 3-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jun  1 22:21:04 user-Lenovo-G50-45 kernel: [267790.187347] usb 3-1.4: Product: USBSerial
Jun  1 22:21:04 user-Lenovo-G50-45 kernel: [267790.187353] usb 3-1.4: Manufacturer: LPCUSB
Jun  1 22:21:04 user-Lenovo-G50-45 kernel: [267790.187359] usb 3-1.4: SerialNumber: DEADC0DE
Jun  1 22:21:04 user-Lenovo-G50-45 kernel: [267790.188792] cdc_acm 3-1.4:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
Jun  1 22:21:04 user-Lenovo-G50-45 mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 8: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.4"
Jun  1 22:21:04 user-Lenovo-G50-45 mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 8 was not an MTP device
```

Edit 2:

Here is how my rules file looks now:

```
KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*",MODE="0666"
KERNEL=="ttyACM[0-9]*",MODE="0666",RUN+="/usr/bin/gnome-terminal"
```

Is there an error? Instead of my program `SQM_ver2` I have tried only to open Terminal, but it does not work. The permissions are set correctly, so the `50-ttyusb.rules` file works at least for that part. Also, looking at my `50-ttyusb.rules` file I think that now all devices that I connect and they get assigned `ttyUSB` or `ttyACM` socket will have read/write permissions (and the program `SQM_ver2` would start). I should probably ask another question on how to set permissions for only this device (probably it should compare `idVendor` and `idProduct`?).

Comment: It should be possible to add a RUN action to your rule (of the form `RUN+="/path/to/SQM_ver2"`). Did you try that? If so, what happened?

Comment: No I did not try this. I will report when I finish to work.

Comment: I have tried to add RUN to rule but nothing happened. Maybe because my SQM program needs terminal for output? I have edited my question to add syslog output.

Comment: @NonStandardModel, Could you try combine my answer on your other question with the one here https://askubuntu.com/questions/625243/how-to-execute-c-program-whenever-a-usb-flash-drive-is-inserted/625705#625705 . then write answer if it works for you otherwise update the question. Let me know. BTW, it is not possible to start a GUI in such confined process of udev, it is only short/quick configuration  scripts or programs. (no daemons, no GUI,no interactive CLI )