# Systemd execute a script everytime a USB-Stick is inserted

Tags: systemd, udev, autostart, usb-drive

I want to launch a script everytime a USB stick is inserted. After experimenting with udev, I tried to accomplish my task with systemd (udev is supposed to run only short tasks).
Systemd works fine except the fact that I have to enter the full path and name of the stick, so it works only with that specific stick. But I like to run the script on any stick. Is there any way of using wildcharts ( .*?)?

Has anyone a hint how to accomplish that task?

Thanks for your help

Comment: - udev with SYSTEMD_WANTS tag. See https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.device.html  -"udev is supposed to run only short tasks" Not entirely true. The task itself might be long running, **activating** the task needs to be short.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I didn't check it yet. Maybe I find today some time to chew trough the whole Systemd stuff and work out my solution.

Comment: @user192299, similar question using udev to run for any usb storage device https://askubuntu.com/questions/625243/how-to-execute-c-program-whenever-a-usb-flash-drive-is-inserted